# what is $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\sin(nx)\over n^2}$$ Then what is $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)$

Now I know the series converges uniformly by $M-Test$ (Take $M_n=1/n^2$). What should be my next step. I am currently reading this topic so please pardon my ignorance if I am missing something very obvious.

Edit:

Thanks to comment by Jerry,

$\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)=0$

Comment: Hint: Uniform convergence implies that the limit can pass into the infinite sum.

Comment: Then the answer should be  0. @Jerry

Comment: I appreciate your bio. that’s me except with bipolar depression and feelings of worthlessness lolol but i’m also thankful for the love of my life of course. But seriously, that’s awesome bro(ette)

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor Thanks a lot Chase Taylor. I will be more than happy to talk to you :)  Just looked at your profile. I really like the hens ;p. How are they doing?

Comment: @StammeringMathematician OH MY GOSH THEY’RE SO GOOD!!!!! I HAVE TWO NEW BABIES!!!!!!!!! They each have different mothers but they’re both being raised by a third mother! They’re just the cutest things. It’s awesome to watch how fast they learn by observation

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor I am afraid we are allowed to chat here, you can drop me an email to stammeringmathematician[at the rate of]gmail.com

Comment: @StammeringMathematician It says stammeringmathematician@gmail.com couldn’t be found and can’t receive mail. Email me `chasetaylortutoring@gmail.com`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By  the Weierstrass $M-$test (as you correctly point out) the series converges uniformly, and so 
$$ \lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=\lim_{x\to 0}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\sin (nx)}{n^2}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin(nx)}{n^2}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty 0=0.$$
The only nontrivial step here was passing the limit through the summation, which is possible given uniform convergence (cf. Rudin or any introductory analysis book).

Answer (score 1):

The proof given by @Antonios-Alexandros Robotis is excellent.

Here is a direct proof, based on the fact that the given expression is the Fourier series representing the $C^{\infty}$ [Clausen function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clausen_function) defined by :

$$Cl_2(\varphi)=-\int_0^{\varphi}\ln|2 \sin\tfrac{x}{2}|dx,$$
which, evidently, is such that $Cl_2(0)=0$.

Remarks :

a) The Fourier series coincides exactly with the Clausen function due to its continuity.

b) Clausen function is connected with many other "special", though important, functions like $\zeta$ function, dilogarithm $Li_2$, etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I always like alternating ways to solve a given problem. Thanks again.